# How to redirect to another .js page/file after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hey I am working on an app and I am trying to redirect to a page in react JS after getting an if block true. But unfortunately i cannot can anyone help me what can be done.

```
async function handleLogin(event){

   
        event.preventDefault();// from elements property
        console.log(event.target.email.value)
        console.log(event.target.password.value)

        let payload = {
            
            "params":{"db":"dev02","login":event.target.email.value, "password":event.target.password.value}
            }
      
        let result = await axios.post('http://dev02.example.net:3000/mobile/session/authenticate', payload);
        console.log(payload)
        console.log(result)
        try{
            
            if (result.data.result.message.toLowerCase() === 'success') {
                
                alert('Hello ABC')
            }

        }
        catch{
            
            alert('Invalid Email or Password')
        }
    }
```

What can i write inside If block to redirect to a page in the same directory as Timesheets.js

```
this.props.history.push('/Timesheets.js')
```

tried this but doesnt worked

```
event.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./Timesheets.js'))
```

tried also this but doesnt work

Trying to get Timesheet.js page if statement is True

Comment: If you know the relative path to current location, try to have a look at [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: I am sorry I do not have much knowledge in that respect. Could you please suggest any alternatives?

Comment: create a route for ```Timesheets.js``` then pass the route name on here ```this.props.history.push('/route name')```. Hopefully it will work.